# How to automatically enter a value on error instead of skipping?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code, which works as long as `Gi` is found in the `Articles` sheet. If `Gi` isn't found I receive an error. I can skip the error using `On Error Resume Next`, but I want to be able to automatically enter a value here. Any suggestions on how? I have found documentation to go somewhere on an error, but that will stop the FOR loop.

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
    Range("N" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("G" & i), Sheets("Articles").Range("A2:B5000"), 2, False)
Next i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you can use an on error goto statement together with a resume.
In the example code I just catch an error in ONE line with that resume, all other errors are handled by a msgbox.

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
    On Error Goto ErrorNext
    lookupValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("G" & i), _
      Sheets("Articles").Range("A2:B5000"), 2, False)
    On Error Goto ErrorHandler
ResumeHere:
    Range("N" & i).Value = lookupValue
Next i

'-------- All of your other code goes here  ------------

Exit Sub
ErrorNext:
    lookupValue = "Some default value"
    Resume ResumeHere
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Another Error occured: " & error
```

If you don't want a "default" error- handler, then replace `On Error goto ErrorHandler` with On Error Goto 0. Otherwise you will create a wonderfull infinit loop if there is an error just after your For- Loop...

So without an error- handler except for that one line the code would look like this:

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
    On Error Goto ErrorNext
    lookupValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("G" & i), _
      Sheets("Articles").Range("A2:B5000"), 2, False)
    On Error Goto 0
ResumeHere:
    Range("N" & i).Value = lookupValue
Next i

'-------- All of your other code goes here  ------------

Exit Sub
ErrorNext:
    lookupValue = "Some default value"
    Resume ResumeHere
```

Basically code without an error handler is always bad. All code that I personally write looks like this:

```
  On Error Goto ErrorHandler
'----------------------------------------

' Here is the real code

'----------------------------------------
EndSub:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  '- Do my error handling here, at least show a "better" message
  MsgBox "An error occured: " & Error & " in line " & Erl
  Resume EndSub
```

My "real" code just comes between the two lines... And this "real" code of course can contain handling a "special" error, that just needs a resume to another position as in the examples above.

Comment: I left out the ErrorHandler option and it runs through the `ErrorNext` and `Resume` section, but I presume something is missing towards the end? Excel crashes when I let it run and I only have 700 rows.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to exit the sub when no error occurs... Fixed it in the code above, just add `Exit Sub` before the ErrorNext- Line. And you can leave out the "normal" error handler. then you should do a `On Error goto 0` instead of the `On Error Goto ErrorHandler`, otherwise you will create an infinite loop whenever any other error occurs

Comment: So I remove `On Error Goto Errorhandler` and `Errorhandler:` completely and replace the first part by `On Error Goto 0`

Comment: One last question. What if I want to add something beneath the FOR loop. Where do I start then?

Comment: holy cow that's an extended example! Thank you very much!